# How to synchronise Google calendar with gnome calendar?

Tags: kubuntu, calendar

Has anyone been able to add a google calendar to the gnome calendar on Kubuntu? It asks for my login but entering the correct credentials does not provide access to it. Can anyone suggest some steps? I'm entering the whole https link under "Add a calendar" option. Oh, almost forgot, is there a better calendar app for Kubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KOrganizer should be a better match for Kubuntu than gnome calendar.After installing:

1. Go to Settings -> Configure KOrganizer.
2. In Settings: Press "General" -> "Calendars" tab -> Add.
3. Search for "Google" and press "Google groupware"
4. Press "Add" and sign in to your google account.

Comment: KOrganizer is way better.